# Gitflow, managing hotfixes, version tags and releases

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm following the GitFlow workflow but I'd like to know how people approach the issue of bugs with versioning/releases

We have a set of features that are linked to versions.

> feature set {A,B,C} --> v1.0.1

> feature set {D,E,F} --> v1.0.2

Each time a feature set is completed we add a tag with the version number to develop branch. This allows development to continue at it's own speed and we can then selectively choose a version, based on the version tag, to cut to our release branch which can end up in SIT, PREPROD etc

Imagine a scenario where the develop branch has a latest version tag of v1.0.10 and Production environment is running v1.0.5. If a bug is noticed in Production

- you apply the fix to hotfix branch
- release hotfix to production
- merge hotfix to main branch
- merge main down to develop and tag with a hotfix reference

**Later on if I wanted to move Production to the next version v1.0.6 and have that hotfix included, how would I do so? Isn't that hotfix only available now post tag v1.0.10 in develop?**

Comment: If you follow SemVer then the patch number is only increased when there is a bugfix - which should probably then also be deployed to production. I always increase minor version when depoloying to production to make sure that the patch versions are available for bug fixes in production.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps with the issue at hand. It's not a question of version numbers but of features associated with them. In this case I'd be trying to give Production the features associated with v1.0.6 plus the hotfix applied when it was at v1.0.5 ... but that hotfix would have been committed to develop at a time when it's latest version tag would now be at v1.0.10  ... how do I cut a new release from develop based on 2 tags, a version tag of v1.0.6 and a hotfix tag of hfx-xxx?

Comment: I feel like you've already used too many digits if the last digit represent feature sets. I would expect to have one digit for bug fixes under the digit for features. So, if I stick with your existing scheme, v1.0.5.1 would have that hotfix. It's branched off of 1.0.5 and has no new features, only the hotfix. And maybe you release 1.0.8, and it needs that hotfix too, so that goes into 1.0.8.1. But if I were to rethink your scheme, it would be 1.5.0, 1.5.1 with hotfix, 1.8.0, 1.8.1 with hotfix, etc. Major is the big overhauls, minor is the feature, and patch is for bug fixes.

Comment: On https://semver.org/ for example, they suggest MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, where your new features than don't break backwards compatibility increment MINOR, not PATCH, and compatibility breaking feature increment MAJOR.

Comment: Whether you want your current scheme, where the third number is for features, or the semver scheme as described there, you need a number in your versioning scheme dedicated to patches, after the last feature-related number.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, that's a good point and I've provided a bad example to illustrate my problem. Using your examples, how do you cut that release to say 1.8.1 from develop to include v1.8.0 functionality plus the recent hotfix. I'm imagining a develop tag history that, once modified to account for your point on spaces for patches, looks like tag-v1.10.0, tag-hfx-100, tag-v1.9.0, tag-v1.8.0 ... Do I take a cut from develop to a new branch release/v1.8.1 based on tag-v1.8.0 and then merge in specific commits associated with hot fix tag-fx-100?

Comment: I think the comments got too caught up on the versioning and tagging mechanism, when I think the crux of the question is really around release timing. It's possible the tagging/versioning of the features isn't even necessary at all until after they are deployed. I've added an answer which discusses some tweaks you could try to address the timing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Git Flow doesn't really handle your specific workflow as you described. Fortunately I believe with a minor workflow tweak you can resolve it.

The standard Git Flow assumes everything on the `develop` branch is going to land in Production (and consequently `master` or in your case `main`), in the *next* release (or the one after if a release is already pending). In the case when a `release` branch exists, and a hotfix goes into `main`, you also merge that `hotfix` (or `main`) back into the `release` branch right away. In your question's scenario, when a release branch doesn't exist yet, you would merge it back into `develop`, and this is where your problem arises because you don't intend to release the tip of `develop` yet, which is where you're deviating from standard Git Flow.

To solve this, I would propose one of these options:

1. As soon as you know which commit on `develop` will represent your next release, create a `release` branch for it. Then if a hotfix hits `main` you can merge `main` back into the `release` branch instead of `develop`, guaranteeing you won't overwrite the hotfix changes in production. Note this might correspond nicely with your `PREPROD` branch, in which case you should make sure it always exists at the time you need to merge hotfixes into `main` back down into it. At that time you might have to also merge `PREPROD` right back down to `develop`. From there, you simply need to make sure that the next time you make `PREPROD` it comes after that new merge in `develop`. If your release cycle is so delayed that even that isn't possible, then that leads us to the next option:
2. You could add a sub-workflow to your existing Git Flow. This is exactly what we do at my organization. The basic concept is that you have another *throwaway* integration branch, which I recommend calling `next`, which is where feature branches go to get hardened. Once they are proven and ready, you re-merge those commits into `develop` which means they will be included in the next `release` branch. Although this adds more complexity, you gain the ability to work out bugs earlier and only merge well-tested code into `develop`. Furthermore, it also enables you to release features out of order if you wish to, because you get to decide which features to merge into `develop`. Since you seem to have a long cycle for hardening your feature branches before they get deployed, this may work well for you. If you go this route I would recommend not tagging those features on the `next` branch, since the `next` branch should be reset to `develop` periodically. You may not need to tag those features at all anymore, and could instead tag the releases containing multiple features, as you deploy them. By the way, this sub-workflow is called [gitworkflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) and is what the [maintainers of Git use](https://hackernoon.com/how-the-creators-of-git-do-branching), but without Git Flow also tacked on to it.

**Side Note:** You may have noticed I mentioned merging `main` back into `release` or `develop` instead of merging the `release` or `hotfix` branches themselves back down as standard Git Flow describes. This is functionally equivalent to the standard Git Flow suggestion, but I prefer this simply so the extra merge commit on `main` gets brought back down too. This way extra merge commits don't collect on `main` over time and get brought down all at once with a hotfix. It also keeps `develop` fully up to date with `main` so you don't see any commit IDs on `main` that aren't present in `develop`.